# tcpdump: can't create rx ring on packet socket

Tags: memory, tcpdump

When I use tcpdump on a Linux Machine. Error happens:

```
$#/usr/sbin/tcpdump dst 183.131.XXX.XXX
tcpdump: can't create rx ring on packet socket: Cannot allocate memory

 $#free -m
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
 Mem:         32111      30685       1426          0       4541      13533
  -/+ buffers/cache:      12610      19501

BASIC INFO:
$#uname -a
Linu  xxxx.xxxxxx.com 2.6.32_1-15-0-0 #1 SMP Fri Sep 01 15:37:59 CST 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Who can help me?  Thx a lot!

Comment: `Cannot allocate memory` looks like `ENOMEM` as translated by `perror(3)`, you may need to search the source to find out why you are being denied,  could be selinux.

Comment: What does `tcpdump -h` print?

Comment: It says : tcpdump version 4.1.1
libpcap version 1.1.1